# \newcommand works with latex but not with tex4ht( htlatex)

Tags: macros, tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax

I am working on 2 rendering, the first one with the classical `latex command` and the other with `htlatex command` (tex4ht).

I have defined the following \newcommand :

```
\newcommand{\btFma}[2]{$\mathfrak{e}_{\mathbf{#1}}$$_{}$$^{\mathbf{#2}}$}                
\newcommand{\btFmb}[2]{$\mathfrak{e}^{\mathbf{#1}}$$_{}$$_{\mathbf{#2}}$}
```

and use them like this :

```
\begin{equation}                                                                         
\,\,\,\,\textrm{\btFma{i}{j}}=\beq{e_{i}}\otimes\beq{e^{j}}\,\,\,\,;\,\,\,\,\textrm{\btFmb{i}{j}}=\beq{e^{i}}\otimes\beq{e_{j}}
\end{equation}
```

The rendering with `latex command` is what I expect :

[image: latex rendering]

You can notice that I want for each of `\newcommand` a little shift between upper and lower indices.

My issue is that I can't reproduce the same rendering with `htlatex command`. Here what is displayed on generated HTML page :

[image: htlatex rendering]

It seems that MathJax doesn't take into account the 2 `\newcommand`.

I produce the HTML page with the following command :

```
htlatex source.tex config_mathjax
```

and config file "`config_mathjax`" :

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                         
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {       
      Macros: {   
        \unexpanded{ 
                     beq: ['{\\mathbf\{\#1\}}',1],
                     btFma: ['{\$\\mathfrak\{e\}_\{\\mathbf\{\#1\}\}\$\$_\{\}\^\{\\mathbf\{\#2\}\}\$}',2],
                     btFmb: ['{\$\\mathfrak\{e\}\^\{\\mathbf\{\#1\}\}\$\$\^\{\}_\{\\mathbf\{\#2\}\}\$}',2],
      },
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }
    },      
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    tex2jax: {     
        \unexpanded{
      inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['\begin{equation}','\end{equation}'], ['\begin{align}','\end{align}'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true
    }                
  });                
</script>
}}
```

I don't understand why `htlatex` doesn't take into accound these 2 `\newcommand`.

Maybe the `\newcommand` \bFma and \bFmb are too complex for htlatex, if someone knows how to simplify them, I will take them.

And if someone has or had the same type of issue, this would be fine to tell me how to circumvent it.

Regards

Comment: this is not `tex4ht` issue, it passes math input verbatim to `MathJax`, as expected. `MathJax` doesn't render your commands for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax only processes macros in math mode, not in text mode (it doesn't include text-mode macros).  That includes inside `\textrm{}` and other commands that switch to text mode.  To use this with MathJax, you would need to remove the `\textrm{}` and change the definition of the macro to expect to one in math mode originally.

Answer (score 1):

Remove dollar signs from definition:

```
\newcommand{\btFma}[2]{\mathfrak{e}_{\mathbf{#1}}{}^{\mathbf{#2}}}
```

Remove `\textrm` from equation:

```
\begin{equation}                                                                         
\btFma{i}{j}
\end{equation}
```

Remove dollars signs from mathjax config:

```
 \unexpanded{ 
 btFma: ['{\\mathfrak e}_{\\mathbf \#1}{}^{\\mathbf \#2}',2],
 }
```

BTW: you can use `\quad` or `\qquad` instead of `\,\,\,\,`